# Configure bean RestTemplate in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

is there way to add http message converter to RestTemplate in Spring Boot by configuration?

I would like to just add new message converted and do not remove the existing ones.

This will remove existing one.

```
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate(ProtobufHttpMessageConverter hmc) {
  return new RestTemplate(Arrays.asList(hmc));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extra converter like this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(hmc);
```